# After hosting codeigniter shows welcome page only

Tags: php, codeigniter

My codeigniter project is working perfect in localhost,but when i hosted it is showing the following.please help.

```
Welcome to CodeIgniter!

The page you are looking at is being generated dynamically by CodeIgniter.

If you would like to edit this page you'll find it located at:

application/views/welcome_message.php
The corresponding controller for this page is found at:

application/controllers/Welcome.php
If you are exploring CodeIgniter for the very first time, you should start by reading the User Guide.

Page rendered in 0.3197 seconds. CodeIgniter Version 3.0.0
```

This project hosted in godaddy web server.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: what is your live URL and main controller name ??

Comment: live url name:http://www.personalfinancemanager.in/  controller name:money_c

Comment: You have to upload **application**, **system**, **index.php** you are missing one of them

Comment: Just check to make sure that all controllers have first letter on file and class name upper case. And you may need index.php in url. And make sure you have the correct base url in.

Answer (score 1):

If you are uploading your project, follow these steps:

1. Make sure you have uploaded **application**, **system**, **index.php**, **.htaccess**.
2. Modify your `config/database.php` with your hosted database.
3. Make sure of URL spellings, because Linux hosting is case-sensitive.
4. Make sure all resources are uploaded to server (CSS, JS, images, etc ...)

### Edit

CodeIgniter 2 `index.php`

```
<?php

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * You can load different configurations depending on your
 * current environment. Setting the environment also influences
 * things like logging and error reporting.
 *
 * This can be set to anything, but default usage is:
 *
 *     development
 *     testing
 *     production
 *
 * NOTE: If you change these, also change the error_reporting() code below
 *
 */
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
 * By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
 */

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        break;
    
        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SYSTEM FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This variable must contain the name of your "system" folder.
 * Include the path if the folder is not in the same  directory
 * as this file.
 *
 */
    $system_path = 'system';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want this front controller to use a different "application"
 * folder then the default one you can set its name here. The folder
 * can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server.  If
 * you do, use a full server path. For more info please see the user guide:
 * http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 *
 */
    $application_folder = 'application';

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * DEFAULT CONTROLLER
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Normally you will set your default controller in the routes.php file.
 * You can, however, force a custom routing by hard-coding a
 * specific controller class/function here.  For most applications, you
 * WILL NOT set your routing here, but it's an option for those
 * special instances where you might want to override the standard
 * routing in a specific front controller that shares a common CI installation.
 *
 * IMPORTANT:  If you set the routing here, NO OTHER controller will be
 * callable. In essence, this preference limits your application to ONE
 * specific controller.  Leave the function name blank if you need
 * to call functions dynamically via the URI.
 *
 * Un-comment the $routing array below to use this feature
 *
 */
    // The directory name, relative to the "controllers" folder.  Leave blank
    // if your controller is not in a sub-folder within the "controllers" folder
    // $routing['directory'] = '';

    // The controller class file name.  Example:  Mycontroller
    // $routing['controller'] = '';

    // The controller function you wish to be called.
    // $routing['function'] = '';


/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  CUSTOM CONFIG VALUES
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * The $assign_to_config array below will be passed dynamically to the
 * config class when initialized. This allows you to set custom config
 * items or override any default config values found in the config.php file.
 * This can be handy as it permits you to share one application between
 * multiple front controller files, with each file containing different
 * config values.
 *
 * Un-comment the $assign_to_config array below to use this feature
 *
 */
    // $assign_to_config['name_of_config_item'] = 'value of config item';



// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// END OF USER CONFIGURABLE SETTINGS.  DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Resolve the system path for increased reliability
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 */

    // Set the current directory correctly for CLI requests
    if (defined('STDIN'))
    {
        chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
    }

    if (realpath($system_path) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_path = realpath($system_path).'/';
    }

    // ensure there's a trailing slash
    $system_path = rtrim($system_path, '/').'/';

    // Is the system path correct?
    if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
    {
        exit("Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
    }

/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Now that we know the path, set the main path constants
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
    // The name of THIS file
    define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

    // The PHP file extension
    // this global constant is deprecated.
    define('EXT', '.php');

    // Path to the system folder
    define('BASEPATH', str_replace("\\", "/", $system_path));

    // Path to the front controller (this file)
    define('FCPATH', str_replace(SELF, '', __FILE__));

    // Name of the "system folder"
    define('SYSDIR', trim(strrchr(trim(BASEPATH, '/'), '/'), '/'));


    // The path to the "application" folder
    if (is_dir($application_folder))
    {
        define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
    }
    else
    {
        if ( ! is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/'))
        {
            exit("Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".SELF);
        }

        define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/');
    }

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 *
 */
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

/* End of file index.php */
/* Location: ./index.php */
```

Comment: now it shows a message like:::Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php

Comment: what are the changes needed in index.php?

Comment: In root dir there is index.php??

Comment: yes,i have index.php in root dir.is that need to remove from the root?

Answer (score 1):

1)Make sure that you have changed your default controller
2)you will find the setting inside config/routes.php
3) Check whether your default controller exist or not

Comment: yes,i changed this.But still i have the same problem.My url is :http://www.personalfinancemanager.in/

Comment: 1) check your folder have all permission or not  2)  

check your index.php file like the error said and look for $system_path and $application_folder. Those folders must exist in the root of your application, if you delete them(which you shouldn't do) or renamed them, it will cause that error

$system_path = 'system';
$application_folder = 'application';